# How to use localiZation in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am creating an iOS app in which user will have option to set their preferred language. I have to display all label heading/text etc. on the basis of user selected language. Till now, I know we can do this using `Localizable.strings` file by adding multiple language files and app will get localized automatically as per language selected by user on iPhone's language Settings. But, my requirement is: I have to provide an option to select language within the app. And basis on this language, I have to change label heading etc. in that particular language irrespective of what language user has selected in his/her iPhone settings.
Can any one give some idea how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: @BuntyMadan this changes app language based on iPhone Language settings. But, I have to change based on language selected within the app.